# How to reload a Windows phone application page without creating a new copy in the memory?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my Windows phone application, I'm trying to reload the application page by using the following code:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Page1.xaml?random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()), UriKind.Relative));
```

I have written the code above to the button click event. The Page1 is reloading fine but every time when I click the button the app memory keep on increasing and at some time app is crashed.

Is there any other way to reload or refresh the page with out creating a new copy of the page in the app memory.

Comment: I think you add page in backstack every time you call your navigation service. WHy you need toi reload this page, for reload data?

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page? You should reload content, not pages.

Comment: I have same problem, while the correct solution seems to reload content, for some reason controls like LongListSelector doesn't refresh very well when they already been dawn on screen, so reload page seems to be the solution... @disklosr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always refresh the content of the page from code by calling Page.Refresh(); or some similar method, but this may not refresh all the content.

If you decide to do a new navigation (and ensure that everything gets to the initial state of the page), you can remove the previously navigated pages from the stack by calling:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("logedin"))
   {
       NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
   }
}
```

Take a look at the NavigationService class, specially the AddBackEntry and RemoveBackEntry methods:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
Frame.Navigate(Frame.Content.GetType());
Frame.GoBack();
```

Source
[enter link description here](http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/windows-8-development/reload-page-in-windows-store-app)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes