# XAML windows phone 7 page only refreshes on first deletion of item, not subsequent

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm currently developing a windows phone 7 app for an assignment.

I have a page which displays a listbox of rooms with area/cost to carpet/ name. When you click on a room it deletes that room from the database and refreshes the page. This works fine for the first click; it deletes it, and refreshes perfectly. However, when you click on another room, it does not refresh the page, although it DOES delete it from the database. It's simple problem, but one that I cannot understand at all.

Here is the selection changed event

```
private void roomListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var room = roomListBox.SelectedItem as Room;

            viewModel.DeleteRoom(room);

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/RoomList.xaml?Refresh = true", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

and the delete room function

```
internal void DeleteRoom(Room deletedRoom)
        {
            var qry = from r in roomDb.Rooms
                      where r.Id == deletedRoom.Id
                      select r;

            var room = qry.FirstOrDefault();

            roomDb.Rooms.DeleteOnSubmit(room);
            roomDb.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you say refresh, do you refer to the NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/RoomList.xaml?Refresh = true", UriKind.Relative));} line of code? If you say that it is deleted then you haven't got the correct path to it...

Comment: By refresh I mean that the page "RoomList.xaml" is navigated to and it displays the listBox of room items MINUS the deleted room. When this is done a second time it continues to display the listBox exactly as before, although it is clearly deleting the room from the database, as if I restart the app and navigate to the page again, the listBox does not display it.

Comment: Try to implement this to your code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127788/how-to-reload-a-windows-phone-application-page-without-creating-a-new-copy-in-th

Comment: If you solve you problem please post what the issue was and how did you fix it, I must say that I m curious

Comment: 1) Try `Tab` event. Not `SelectionChanged` event. 2) Try with Observable Collections. 3) If you load/redirectthe same page again try this `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/RoomList.xaml?id={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), UriKind.Relative))`;

Comment: @SimonBates have you found the solution?